# Site and Object mapping is not working after Salesforce and Alfresco integration

Tags: salesforce, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I have integrated Alfresco with Salesforce using Salesforce content connector app, and I am also able to see all Alfresco repository contents in Salesforce, but I am not able to do Site and Object mapping in Salesforce.
I am able to see all alfresco sites and able to see the sites, but I am not able to see any Object type name after selecting any site.

Attached are the screen shots for your reference.

If anyone have faced any similar issue, then please help me with this object mapping in Alfresco and Salesforce.

Thanks In Advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is anyone completed this integration before? can someone please share the steps for this metadata mapping in Alfresco and Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Enterprise edition? I understand that the Salesforce Connector is for Enterprise only.

Comment: you are correct, it is available only for Enterprise. but I am just implementing this as a POC for our COE LAB. I am already able to integrate it but facing issues for metadata mapping.

Comment: I'd recommend reaching out to the Alfresco customer support portal.